# Clarification needed regarding streaming responses with Aqueduct

Tags: dart, aqueduct

I'm reading docs of Aqueduct HTTP web server for Dart.
In the section about [streaming](https://aqueduct.io/docs/http/request_and_response/) response body I see following 2 statements which do not completely fit together for me:

> A body object may also be a `Stream<T>`. `Stream<T>` body objects are most
>   often used when serving files. This allows the contents of the file to
>   be streamed from disk to the HTTP client without having to load the
>   whole file into memory first.

and

> When a body object is a `Stream<T>`, the response will not be sent until
>   the stream is closed. For finite streams - like those from opened
>   filed - this happens as soon as the entire file is read.

So how does it send the response only after the entire file is read without having to load the whole file into memory first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a great question and the wording in the docs could be improved. The code that matters is here: https://github.com/stablekernel/aqueduct/blob/master/aqueduct/lib/src/http/request.dart#L237.

The outgoing HTTP response is a stream, too. When you write bytes to that stream, the bytes are transmitted across the wire (if you enable buffering, which is on by default, a buffer is built up before sending; IIRC this is 8kb by default).

Your source stream - the stream representing your body object - is piped to the HTTP response stream (after being transformed by any codecs, if applicable). As soon as you return the Response object from your controller, your source stream starts being consumed. The response cannot be completed until the source stream indicates it is 'closed'. If you take a peek at the source for `FileController`, you can see that it uses `File.openRead`, which automatically closes the source stream once all bytes have been read.

If your source stream is manually controlled, you return your `Response` object and then asynchronously add bytes to the stream and close it once complete. The key takeaway is that if you own the stream, you need to close it, and system utilities will typically close the stream for you. Hope this answers the question.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I was pretty sure that it is the wording and streaming should be streaming :)
Will try to experiment with piping `Stream.periodic`.

Comment: Joe, I've tried to add a route `/streaming` in my channel. In the `entryPoint` I've linked to this route the following function: `final Stream<String> stream = Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (i) => "$i"); return Response.ok(stream);`. But when I test this route in browser/curl/wget it returns 200 Ok response with a single line "0". So it returns the first event of the stream and closes the response, though I do not close my stream manually. I expected that it will keep the response pending forever/timeout and getting a new piece of the response every second.